# How to manage two-dimensional data

Tags: data-structures, dataset

I have a dataset about a machinery with more than 70 2d-tables (an example attached) [example of 2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Te8e.png) 
Columns and rows are range of measures (pressure, temperature, vibration ecc) and cells contain the count of the occurences during an unkonwn range of time (for example in the second table, cell D10 tells that volume was between 40-60 and pressure was between 20-25 two times).
I have this kind of dataset for 100 machineries and I don't know how to manage in order to analyze them for classification/anomaly detection purpose in R.

Comment: To be clear, your question is about how to import this data into R?  What have you tried?

Comment: No, I would like just a suggestion to understand which is the best way to use this data. In this moment I have trasformed all tables NxM in  tables with 1 row and (N*M) columns. In this way I can have a dataset with one row for each machinery.

Comment: But in this way I loose the information about the ranges of the measures...

Comment: You merge all the tables into one (take a look at `rbind()`), add one more column for machine id or name. Then you can perform any standard classification algorithm.

Comment: I cant because those tables have different dimensions